# How many channels can Redis (redis-py) handle?

Tags: redis, redis-py

I have a task of using pub/sub for great number of listeners. Here is simplified example of subscription from [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis):

```python
r = redis.StrictRedis(...)
p = r.pubsub()
p.subscribe('my-first-channel', 'my-second-channel', ...)

for message in p.listen():
...     # do something with the message
```

Suppose I will subscribe a client for a channel `client-#id`. One channel for each client. The question is: is it ok to use this method if I will have hundreds or thousands of users? Should I subscribe all of them for one channel and encode `user-#id` in the message to filter on receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of how you provision your Redis and the amount of traffic that you'll be generating. A client subscription is just a network connection so you can have quite a few of these. Redis is pretty powerful, and can easily saturate the server's NICs even on a relatively weak CPU core, so if all your 100K's of clients are communicating all the time that could be a bottleneck. In such cases, you'd want to deploy a Redis cluster to scale out and handle the load.